# Finding the image of set under a Möbius transformation

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

A Möbius transformation maps the points $0$, $-i$, and $\infty$ to $10$, $5-5i$, and $5+5i$, respectively. The question is to find the image of the set $S = \{ z: \operatorname{Re}(z) < 0 \}$.

I have tried doing this using the cross ratio method and that yields a longish calculation. The trouble is this is from a previous competitive examination and is supposed to be done usually under $3$ minutes. Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set of lines and circles is preserved by any Mobius transformation. The unique line $L$ passing through $0$, $-i$ and $\infty$ must therefore be mapped to the unique circle $C$ passing through $10$, $5-5i$, $5+5i$, and that circle $C$ is the circle of radius $5$ centered on the point $5$. So the set $S$, which is one of the two half-planes bounded by $L$, must be mapped to either the inside of $C$ or the outside of $C$.

You could therefore complete this problem by picking a single point of $S$ and seeing where it goes: to the inside or to the outside of $C$?

Alternatively, you could also notice that the orientation of $L$ that starts at $0$ and points downward through $-i$ heading towards $\infty$ must be taken to the orientation of $C$ that starts at $10$ and points clockwise through $5-5i$ heading towards $5+5i$. That tells you that $S$, which is the left side of $L$, must map to the inside of $C$.

Comment: Ah finally somewhat clear. Thank you so much!

Comment: "So the set S, which is one of the two half-planes bounded by L, must be mapped to either the inside of C or the outside of C"

I have seen some more similar arguments while reading mobius transform. Why is this true? Any intuition for this would be much helpful
.

Comment: You say that we can check by picking a point of S and checking where it goes. But how can we do this if we don't have the explicit function?

Comment: Finally understood after reading more about it. The transformation preserves orientation of the area wrt the points.